# Odd c++/java multi threading performance results compared to single thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading

I was struggling since 2 days to understand what is going on with c++ threadpool performance compared to a single thread, then I decided to do the same on java, this is when I noticed that the behaviour is same on c++ and java.. basically my code is simple straight forward.

```
package com.examples.threading
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class ThreadPool {

final static AtomicLong lookups = new AtomicLong(0);
final static AtomicLong totalTime = new AtomicLong(0);

public static class Task implements Runnable 
{
    int start = 0;
    Task(int s) {
        start = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
       for (int j = start ; j < start + 3000; j++ ) {
        long st = System.nanoTime();
        boolean a = false;
        long et = System.nanoTime();
        totalTime.getAndAdd((et - st));
        lookups.getAndAdd(1l);
       }
    }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // change threads from 1 -> 100 then you will get different numbers
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) 
    {
        if (i % 3000 == 0) {
            Task task = new Task(i);
            executor.execute(task);
            System.out.println("in time " + (totalTime.doubleValue()/lookups.doubleValue()) + " lookups: " + lookups.toString());
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        ;
    }
    System.out.println("in time " + (totalTime.doubleValue()/lookups.doubleValue()) + " lookups: " + lookups.toString());
}

}
```

now same code when you run with different pool number say like 100 threads, the overall elapsed time will change.

```
one thread:
in time 36.91493612774451 lookups: 1002000


100 threads:
in time 141.47934530938124 lookups: 1002000
```

the question is, the code is same why the overall elapsed time is different what is exactly  going on here..

Comment: Just for thoroughness, try *exactly* the number of hardware cores on the machine for your pool size (less one for that spinning busy-loop in `main`, which is itself a problem).

Comment: Please understand that multi-threaded code is *not* more performant than single-threaded code. Thread management / context switching etc will always take longer to execute than the equivalent code in a single thread. The reason for multi-threading is not to make intensive tasks execute quicker... it is to allow an application to respond to other inputs or process different taks on different cores while processing or blocking actions are happening concurrently.

Comment: @MattCoubrough yes but the time calculation is being done in the task void run itself inside the loop no blocking no waiting nothing .. why we have different numbers !!

Comment: @WhozCraig even with 2 threads I'm still getting different numbers.

Comment: When you have more than 1 thread, the JVM has to manage scheduling of the threads, so right there you have overhead that is unaccounted for in a single thread solution.  And when you have 100 threads, way more threads than cores, you're going to spend a lot more time managing thread contexts than actually running, so not surprised at all.  As @MattCoubrough pointed out, multi-threadedness is a scaling tool, not a performance tool.

Comment: @ScottSosna, I still don't get it, if you looked at the code, I'm calculating the time is needed by boolean a = false; is the execution of this line going to be affected by how many threads are currently running ?

Comment: If the start time was captured but then the thread was swapped out (essentially) so 1 or more other threads execute, the assignment of a and capturing of the end time can happen at some arbitrarily later time, increasing the total time.

Comment: the only way to guarantee that all three statements execute sequentially, uninterrupted is to put a synchronized() block around it that makes a throttle point for all the threads you're kicking off.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of obvious possibilities here.

One is that `System.nanoTime` may serialize internally, so even though each thread is making its call separately, it may internally execute those calls in sequence (and, for example, queue up calls as they come in). This is particularly likely when nanoTime directly accesses a hardware clock, such as on Windows (where it uses Windows' `QueryPerformanceCounter`).

Another point at which you get essentially sequential execution is your atomic variables. Even though you're using lock-free atomics, the basic fact is that each has to execute a read/modify/write as an atomic sequence. With locked variables, that's done by locking, then reading, modifying, writing, and unlocking. With lock-free, you eliminate some of the overhead in doing that, but you're still stuck with the fact that only one thread can successfully read, modify, and write a particular memory location at a given time.

In this case the only "work" each thread is doing is trivial, *and* the result is never used, so the optimizer can (and probably will) eliminate it entirely. So all you're really measuring is the time to read the clock and increment your variables.

To gain at least some of the speed back, you could (for one example) give thread thread its own `lookups` and `totalTime` variable. Then when all the threads finish, you can add together the values for the individual threads to get an overall total for each.

Preventing serialization of the timing is a little more difficult (to put it mildly). At least in the obvious design, each call to `nanoTime` directly accesses a hardware register, which (at least with most typical hardware) can only happen sequentially. It could be fixed at the hardware level (provide a high-frequency timer register that's directly readable per-core, guaranteed to be synced between cores). That's a somewhat non-trivial task, and (more importantly) most current hardware just doesn't include such a thing.

Other than that, do some meaningful work in each thread, so when you execute in multiple threads, you have *something* that can actually use the resources of your multiple CPUs/cores to run faster.